# How to get div image to resize maintaining aspect ratio, yielding to another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a main div containing a chat_bubble and a character_image div next to each other. When the screen is not wide enough I want the character_image div to be under the chat_bubble div which works as expected.

But when the screen height can't contain the character_image, I want the image to shrink maintaining the aspect ratio, filling no more than 30% of the height.

I thought I could do that with max-height: 30% but as you can see the character_image div doesn't shrink regardless of the screen height, and instead creates a scroll bar while cutting off the chat_bubble div, which should take priority and should never be cut off or shrunk.

[image]

Here's a CodePen with my full CSS and html code if anyone could help.

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

```
#main {
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#chat_bubble    {
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
    background: ghostwhite !important;
    float: left;
}

#character_image  {
    max-widgth: 30%;
    max-height: 30%;
    object-fit:contain;
    background: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: a CodeSandbox/Codepen example would help :)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking

Comment: Sorry, I included an image that somehow got deleted when I edited my post. In the image you can see the pink container gets cut off to make space for the character image. I want the opposite to happen. I need the pink container (chat_bubble) to be a fixed size relative to the screen, but for the character_image container to shrink to make room for it, maintaining the aspect ratio.

Comment: afaik - the max-height property requires that the parent have a height set. If the parent's height isn't set explicitly somewhere, my recollection is the behaviour you describe - i.e nothing changes.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem. One more thing if you don't mind me asking. If I shrink the screen vertically, the character_image container cuts off the image. I need it to maintain the aspect ratio when shrinking instead of just cutting it off vertically. I tried object-fit: contain and object-fit: cover since I thought that was the issue. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tGeQmVw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `max-height: 30vh` on the `img` so it wont go over 30% of vertical height of the viewport.